Bokeh s.replaceAll
I am trying to create a PyQt5 app with a Bokeh plot in a QtWebEngineWidget.
While doing so I get an Error:
js: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: s.replaceAll is not a function

For a proof of concept I tried to use the code from this answer.
To get it working on newer Bokeh versions, I updated
p = plotting.figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)

to
p = plotting.figure(width=300, height=300)

Now when I run the program and click on 'Submit', instead of the expected output, I see nothing and the terminal shows js: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: s.replaceAll is not a function.
I'm using a virtual environment and my versions are:

Python: 3.12.6
PyQt5: 5.15.11
PyQtWebEngine: 5.15.7
Bokeh: 3.6.0

The complete code looks like this:
import pandas as pd
from bokeh import plotting, embed, resources
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Submit")
        self.m_output = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

        button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_output)
        self.resize(640, 480)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        p = plotting.figure(width=300, height=300)
        data = {"Day": [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1], "Num": [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        p.hexbin(df.Day, df.Num, size=0.5)
        html = embed.file_html(p, resources.CDN, "my plot")
        self.m_output.setHtml(html)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())



Most likely you need a newer qt version that uses a newer chrome version under the hood. replaceAll was introduced in chrome 85.

@bigreddot According to https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/ 5.15.11 from July 2024 is the newest version, but chrome 85 was released in 2020 so that's quite odd. I also tried other Python versions (3.13.0 and 3.12.7) but that also did not work.

It has nothing to do with the Python version, at all. And ultimately it depends on the underlying version of Qt, not the Python bindings for Qt ("PyQt"). There are already several Qt6 versions out. To use those you would need PyQt6, which is separate: https://pypi.org/project/PyQt6/ FWIW this page lists what versions of Qt have which versions of Chrome inside: https://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine/ChromiumVersions

@ole When dealing with software support, the release date is completely irrelevant, only the version number is. The latest 5.15.* branch of Qt (which also is the latest minor version in the Qt5 series) uses Chromium 87 (see the related page), but AFAIK the default release of PyQt ships with 5.15.2 (the latest Qt5 open source release available for all platforms), which only supports Chromium 80. Also, since PyQt is a Python binding of another library, and you're having issues related with that library, the Python version is also irrelevant.

@ole a 5.15.6 open source version was also released 2 years ago, but unless the PyQt maintainer decides to support that version, your only options are to either build both Qt and PyQt on your own with that version, or switch to PyQt6.

@bigreddot yes, using PyQt6 was the solution, I did not know about this. Thank you!
